# Linux Command for Check Upstream and Downstream

Tags: linux, command

Anyone know what is linux command for check upstream and downstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that refers to bandwidth, check :

```
jnettop
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many commands available. However i prefer to use iptraf. For more information, please visit.
http://iptraf.seul.org/2.1/manual.html